# MultipartEntityBuilder setMode() not working

Tags: apache-httpcomponents

Using apache httpcomponents-client-4.3.6-bin libs.
This code is producing an HttpEntity intance with both parts containing the Content-Tranfer-Encoding header. I can't eliminate these headers using setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE) or setLaxMode(). Does anyone have any suggestions please?

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
List<ContentType> contentTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
contentTypeList.add(ContentType.create("application/x-dmas+json"));
contentTypeList.add(ContentType.create("application/exe"));
int idx = 0;
while(paramKeysIt.hasNext()) {
   builder.addBinaryBody(key = paramKeysIt.next(), params.get(key), contentTypeList.get(idx++),      params.get(key).getName());
}       
HttpEntity reqEntity = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. By POSTing my request to an echo server I am able to see that the Content-Transfer-Encoding headers are indeed absent, even though they show up clearly, and repeatedly in the debugger!
Using NetBeans IDE 8.0